# How to save and load Tree in and from text file with stanford lex parser?

Tags: file, parsing, tree, lex, stanford-nlp

I am building Trees using following lines.

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("englishPCFG.ser.gz"); 
Tree smsTree = lp.apply("how to store Tree to file & then Load !");
```

I want to store these tree to some file and then load it when needed.
Is there any method to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure that out myself.  So far, I've found that it can be converted to XML.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
...
StringWriter strwriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(strwriter);
...
Tree parse = lp.parse(sentence);
parse.indentedXMLPrint(printwriter, false);
String xmlstring = strwriter.toString();
//save xmlstring to file
```

It also appears the MemoryTreebank class might be of use here (https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/2008-March/000026.html). For example, you could simply save the Tree as a string in the normal representation you get from tree.pennString() and then:

```
MemoryTreebank tb2 = new MemoryTreebank(new PennTreeReaderFactory());
tb2.load(new StringReader(s1.toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple with any of the classes implementing the [Treebank](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Treebank.html)
interface. The example below uses the DiskTreebank class.

Consider you have a directory where you have written the Penn strings to individual files using toString() method of the Tree class.

You can read all the trees in this directory using the following code snippet

```
private void loadAndDisplayTrees() 
{
    DiskTreebank dtb = new DiskTreebank();
    dtb.loadPath(new File("pathToYourDirectory"), null);
    //The second argument in the above method is a FileFilter.

    Iterator<Tree> it = dtb.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Tree t = it.next();
        System.out.println(t);          
    }
}
```